# Displaying conditional mysql values in additional column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

> In a sample project i wanted to display data in such a way that based on dates the records for same student comes in additional columns.

`mysql> desc sch_student;`

```
+----------------+--------------+
| Field          | Type         |
+----------------+--------------+
| s_first_name   | varchar(128) |
| s_last_name    | varchar(128) |
| rollcode       | int(8)       |
| regnum         | int(8)       |
| in_time        | datetime     |
| out_time       | datetime     |
| total_time     | int(8)       |
+----------------+--------------+
```

> for below query i am getting sample output like below , my expected output is something i am unable to get. I tried Sample join but it didn't work.

```
mysql> select * from sch_student;
    +-------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| s_first_name      | s_last_name   | rollcode     | regnum    | in_time             | out_time            | total_time     |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| Suzan             | Matsuo        | 8900         | 2897      | 2017-12-02 22:30:11 | 2017-12-02 22:30:11 | 00:17:00       |
| Scottie           | Ogletree      | 5624         | 5627      | 2017-12-02 16:40:01 | 2017-12-02 16:40:05 | 00:26:04       |
| Cynthia           | Zimmerman     | 3107         | 6348      | 2017-12-02 16:35:01 | 2017-12-02 16:35:01 | 00:59:89       |
| Ricardo           | Shurtliff     | 3072         | 261       | 2017-12-02 15:33:01 | 2017-12-02 15:33:01 | 00:16:55       |
| Elizabeth         | Milligan      | 4722         | 3233      | 2017-12-02 15:06:00 | 2017-12-02 15:10:33 | 00:14:33       |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Expected output is something like below

```
+-------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| s_first_name      | s_last_name   |                         Today's Meeting                                               |                         Day Before Yesterday's Meeting                                |
|                                   | rollcode     | regnum    | in_time             | out_time            | total_time     | rollcode     | regnum    | in_time             | out_time            | total_time     |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| Suzan             | Matsuo        | 8900         | 2897      | 2017-12-02 22:30:11 | 2017-12-02 22:30:11 | 00:17:00       | 8900         | 2897      | 2017-11-30 12:30:11 | 2017-11-30 12:50:11 | 00:17:00       |
| Scottie           | Ogletree      | 5624         | 5627      | 2017-12-02 16:40:01 | 2017-12-02 16:40:05 | 00:26:04       | 5624         | 5627      | 2017-11-30 18:40:01 | 2017-11-30 19:33:05 | 00:26:04       |
| Cynthia           | Zimmerman     | 3107         | 6348      | 2017-12-02 16:35:01 | 2017-12-02 16:35:01 | 00:59:89       | 3107         | 6348      | 2017-11-30 13:35:01 | 2017-11-30 14:15:01 | 00:59:89       |
| Ricardo           | Shurtliff     | 3072         | 261       | 2017-12-02 15:33:01 | 2017-12-02 15:33:01 | 00:16:55       | 3072         | 261       | 2017-11-30 19:33:01 | 2017-11-30 20:33:01 | 00:16:55       |
| Elizabeth         | Milligan      | 4722         | 3233      | 2017-12-02 15:06:00 | 2017-12-02 15:10:33 | 00:14:33       | 4722         | 3233      | 2017-11-30 18:06:00 | 2017-11-30 19:10:33 | 00:14:33       |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

> I tried below join and it's not returning expected output. Is it possible to display conditional column from table?

```
    select * from 
(
    (select s_first_name,s_last_name,rollcode,regnum,in_time from sch_student where sch_student.in_time BETWEEN CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE() ) As TD,    
    (select s_first_name,s_last_name,rollcode,regnum,in_time from sch_student where sch_student.in_time BETWEEN CURDATE()- INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE() ) As DBYS
) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. I haven't tested it. Basically the query gets todays data LEFT joins to the day before yesterday's data. I assumed regnum and rollcode makes your primary key. Change if that isnt the case.

```
SELECT TD.* , DBYS.*
FROM (
    SELECT s_first_name
        ,s_last_name
        ,rollcode
        ,regnum
        ,in_time
    FROM sch_student
    WHERE sch_student.in_time BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND CURDATE()) AS TD
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s_first_name
        ,s_last_name
        ,rollcode
        ,regnum
        ,in_time
    FROM sch_student
    WHERE sch_student.in_time BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
            AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS DBYS 
ON (TD.regnum = DBYS.regnum AND 
    TD.rollcode = DBYS.rollcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get info for today's meeting and the "day-before-yesterday's" meeting, try using a LEFT JOIN instead:

```
SELECT s_first_name, s_last_name, rollcode, regnum, in_time 
FROM sch_student AS sch_today
LEFT JOIN sch_student AS sch_daybeforeyesterday ON 
  sch_today.<PK_FIELD> = sch_daybeforeyesterday.<PK_FIELD> AND 
  sch_daybeforeyesterday.in_time BETWEEN CURDATE()- INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
WHERE sch_student.in_time BETWEEN CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

This will give you all rows with "in_time" within the last 0-24 hours.  For each of those rows, it will return any corresponding rows with "in_time" within the 48-72 hours.